# How to make an inline list absolutely without labels?

Tags: enumitem

I'm trying to render an inline list that has absolutely no labels:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
I like
\begin{itemize*}[afterlabel=,label=]
    \item apples,
    \item bananas,
    and
    \item oranges.
\end{itemize*}
\end{document}
```

However, it doesn't render exactly right. I see an extra space at the end of each item, when the list is longer than a paragraph.

Why I need this? I just like to have my TeX sources structured this way, with `\item` in front of every item.

Comment: Inline lists have their own parameters (see page 15 of [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)). In your case, if you append `itemjoin={}`, you should get the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) has other parameters that control inline lists. In your example, you can change `itemjoin`, which works as a separator for the items. For instance, see the code below, which is slightly different version of yours

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
I like
\begin{itemize*}[afterlabel={},label={},itemjoin={\space},]
    \item apples,
    \item bananas,
    \item aaaaa,
    \item bbbb
      and
    \item oranges.
\end{itemize*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The output, as you see, doesn't really look nice/correct. Can you make it look properly, with spaces after commas and without a comma after `and`?

Comment: See the updated answer.